# Finding the Proportions of Topological Disks

Tags: general-topology, geometry, computational-mathematics, computational-geometry, tiling

I am currently in the process of writing an internal software package that will be used for computational geometry research. I am interested in being able to programatically generate isotoxal topological tiles and various other types of tiles for that matter.

[image]

To represent the tiles, I need to know their precise proportions in order to generate coordinates for each of the vertices — therein lies my problem. How am I to obtain this information from research papers, for example, that otherwise make no precise specifications? (see [Equilateral k-Isotoxal Tiles](http://faculty.washington.edu/cemann/equilateral-isotoxal.pdf))

Update: Extensive research has not yielded any productive answers. I would certainly appreciate some direction. I plan to meet with some faculty at my university to further discuss the issue at hand.

Comment: Instead of giving a link to a lengthy paper, you should summarise in your question the relevant features of such tilings.

Comment: @Aretino My question does not regard the characteristics of Isotoxal tiles, but rather, representing tiles of all sorts programatically without being given their precise dimensions